# Can ‘Walk the walk’ stand alone?

Tags: phrases

I found the phrase "walk the walk" in President Obama's remark on budget cuts in the Washington Post's *Today's Quote (Feb. 15)*. As I was unfamiliar with this phrase, I checked an online dictionary (www.phrase.org), that told me *walk the walk* means *a lot of things are easier to talk about than to do*, and is almost always said in combination with *talk the talk* (for example, *if you're going to talk the talk, you've got to walk the walk*).

However, President used *walk the walk* alone, not accompanied by *talk the talk*.

Is www.phrase.org’s *walk the walk* definition that the phrase is almost always accompanied by *talk the talk* wrong? 
How can I interpret *walk the walk* in the specific context of the following President Obama’s remark? And what is the origin of *walk the walk*? Is this a well-worn idiom?

> It would mean cutting things that I care deeply about. But if we're going to walk the walk when it comes to fiscal discipline, these kinds of cuts will be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might mention that I've heard people who are *not* native English speakers regularly confuse this phrase, and instead say, "Walk the talk & talk the walk."

+1 to Manoochehr for affirming that "Talk the talk" can stand alone, not least because listeners will customarily complete the phrase in their minds anyway.

Comment: Here's what the [OED online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0935970#m_en_gb0935970) has to say, "Walk the walk (also walk the talk): informal , chiefly North American, suit one‘s actions to one’s words." Here's another link to the [Washington Post](http://onfaith.washingtonpost.com/onfaith/panelists/john_esposito/2011/02/time_to_walk_the_talk_in_mideast.html)

Comment: Wow; I always thought that phrasing was wrong. Actually, I still do.

Comment: @fortunate1: This sounds like a pet peeve.. the kind of stuff you find in books called "Common Mistakes in English" or those blogs that rant about how everyone else is murdering the language. Here's another link to an editorial in the New York Times, the title of which is "Walk the Talk": http://www.nytimes.com/2010/06/06/opinion/06sun3.html I also wanted to say that this answer would have made more sense as a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the logic in this alternative construction; I won't use the phrase that way, though. [EDIT: "this answer" meaning my "I might mention...", you mean?]

Comment: @fortunate1: Hah.. I don't use it that way either. I just think that if usage is well-documented and idiomatic, it is incorrect to call it incorrect. Also, if non-native English speakers _regularly_ confuse this phrase (which I don't think is the case here.. it looks like everyone, from the guys at OED to the NYT to the Washington Post, is using this), it would mean it is accepted usage for them, and therefore, correct:-) Yes, I meant the "I might mention..." It doesn't seem like an answer to the question, unless you meant it as one.

Comment: @tc: I'm really not as peevish as I may sound, and if others want to use this flipped version, I won't snap at them. Then again, I'd have thought the sort of person attracted to this site would possess some inner gyroscope that balances most truly when the grammar looks and feels right -quite apart from what _accepted usage_ propounds. Using _it's_ to denote possession is fairly widespread, too, but I wouldn't call it correct. [And yes, I should have posed my answer as a comment -still getting the hang of this site's etiquette. Sorry.]

Comment: @fortunate1: I apologize if that sounded a bit short. I didn't mean any offence. It's good to get differing points of view.. I hadn't even thought about "walk the walk" and "walk the talk" until today, and then suddenly got very interested in it:-) I'm relatively new to the site too, and still don't know how some of it works (there seem to be levels within levels within levels, with the meta and the StackOverflow and...) Ah well, we'll get the hang of it when we do.

Answer (score 7):

It's not **always** accompanied by "Talk the Talk", though they're rhyming expressions. It can stand alone as it's used in the example below.

According to [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

> **Walk the Walk:** *to do the things that people expect or think are necessary in a particular situation*

Example:

> People are motivated by leaders who actually walk the walk.
>
> Walk the Walk with us! The time for talk is over.