# talking the walk

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

In a performance called ["Walking with Richard Wentworth"](http://www.iconeye.com/404/item/2785-review-walking-with-richard-wentworth-%7C-icon-051-%7C-september-2007),  Richard Wentworth and a group of participants walk in London streets and he talks about the urban environments around to them. A chapter of the book I am reading that is dedicated to this performance is titled **"Talking the Walk"**. Somewhere else in the text of the book I found the phrase **"talks that walk"** again, that could be seen below. I want to know if "talking the walk" here means "talking about walking", "talking while walking", or does it have anything to do with the phrase "talk the talk and walk the walk"?

Context:

> Thus, where Wentworth takes you for a walk, and ‘**talks that walk**’,
>   Alys tends to provide templates or recipes for walks or walking
>   actions – sometimes involving the mobilisation of considerable numbers
>   of participants – in which certain narratives, formations or rhythms
>   emerge.
>
> art and the city by Nicolas Whybrow

Comment: Related or even possible dupe: ["Walk the walk" vs. "talk the talk" vs. "walk the talk"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/192777/55623). See also the Yoichi Oishi special: [Can ‘Walk the walk’ stand alone?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12779/55623).

Comment: 'Talk' and 'walk' are only marginally transitive. 'He talks the talk but doesn't walk the walk' means that his words sound admirable, but his actions don't match. It's a well-known expression. Here, I'm guessing another level of unusualness is added to the original expression, for effect (though the modified expression became the more popular). As you imply, other expressions would be more usual.

Comment: It's a play on "walk the talk", but likely derives little meaning from that idiom.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the expression "Talk the talk but not walk the walk" is a complete **red herring** here, ie has no bearing on the question.

I think that "talking the walk" hear means "talk you through the walk", or "explain the walk in detail".

So, when the author says

> *Thus, where Wentworth takes you for a walk, and ‘talks that walk’*

they mean that Wentworth is talking as he goes along the walk, explaining to his companions why he chose that route, and describing various interesting features, etc.

Comment: It's not a red herring at all. It's such an obvious in-your-face reference that it hurts.

Comment: @RegDwigнt it may well be a play-on-words reference to that expression, you're right, so perhaps "red herring" is putting it too strongly.  But the expression doesn't help with the meaning.